# TypeError: Meteor.user(...).services is undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to get a Meteor user's Facebook ID (who is signed in through Facebook). The following line is giving me trouble:

```
var userID = Meteor.user().services.facebook.id;
```

In the console it says

```
TypeError: Meteor.user(...).services is undefined
```

From my understanding this is because the user().services hasn't been initialized yet. I wrapped the code in `if(Meteor.user())` to confirm the user has been initialized. The code is executed when a button is pressed, so it definitely has enough time to start. This started happening when I removed autopublish (although that could be unrelated). Is there anything additional I need to do to make it work without autopublish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it with the following:

```
Meteor.publish("getUserData", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
});
```

and subscribing to that. Once that subscription is filled all of the Meteor.user.services data is available.

Comment: Just want to point out that this is pretty risky from a security point of view. You've created a publication that allows *any* user (even a non-logged in one) to get access to the entire user object *for any user*.

Answer (score 0):

The *services* key is not included by default in the user's document on the client because it contains security details. You could fetch it via a method call or publish it specifically from the server and subscribe to it.

Comment: What kind of method call would I use to fetch it?

Comment: Create a server method that returns the key you want, then call it from the client with `Meteor.call()`

Comment: how can I fetch it outside of meteorjs ? like through nodeJS

Comment: It would be a mongodb query to the db.users collection.